# How can I optimize this code to reduce the evaluation time

Tags: java, algorithm

I was solving a question which requires me to print all the numbers from an integer array which have 1,2,3 in them. For example an array a containing [123,300, 456,789] will give the output as [123,300]. 
In my codes I have used ArrayList and all those things which are needed to solve it. Still the evaluation time is not upto mark.

```
public static void take(int[] a) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> ai = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) 
    {
        int temp =a[i];
        while(a[i]>0) 
        {
            int b=a[i]%10;
            if(b==1||b==2||b==3) 
            {
                ai.add(temp);
                break;
            }
            a[i]= a[i]/10;
        }
    }
    if(ai.isEmpty()) 
    {
        System.out.println(-1);
    }
    else 
    {
        ai.sort(null);
        System.out.println(ai);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner mew = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=mew.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<t;i++) 
    {
        int n=mew.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        for(int j=0; j<n;j++) 
        {
           a[j] = mew.nextInt();
        }
        take(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean "not up to mark"?  What timings have you taken so far?  SUGGESTION: Try a simple loop that just converts every number into a string and checks for the characters '1', '2' or '3'.  Compare the timing with your original version.

Comment: Do you need to sort?

Comment: If your code works and is just a bit slow, you should probably try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not upto the mark meaning?

Answer (score 1):

All you need, is just convert the `number` to the string; retrieve all characters and check either required characters exists or not using `Set`:

```
public static Set<Integer> take(int[] a, char[] markers) {
    Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        String str = String.valueOf(a[i]);

        for (char marker : markers) {
            if (str.contains(String.valueOf(marker))) {
                numbers.add(a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

As alternative, you can use streams:

```
public static Set<Integer> take(int[] a, char[] markers) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
                 .boxed()
                 .filter(val -> {
                     String str = String.valueOf(val);

                     for (char marker : markers)
                         if (str.contains(String.valueOf(marker)))
                             return true;

                     return false;
                 })
                 .sorted()
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: I think you can combine this with the other answer and have `.filter(str -> str.matches(".*[1-3].*"))`

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution, but my question was not specific to this problem. May I know how I can reduce the compilation time of my solutions, like few basic rules?

Comment: In terms of efficiency, streams and extra data-structures such as sets are overkill. Readibility certainly improves, but that was not the original goal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to textually search if the number 1, 2 or 3 is present at least 1 time. You can do this with a regex like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class So {
    public static void searchForNumbers(int[] sourceArray) {
        System.out.println("source array = " + Arrays.toString(sourceArray));
        List<Integer> ai = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
            if( Integer.toString(sourceArray[i]).matches(".*[1-3].*")) {
                ai.add(sourceArray[i]);
            }
        }
        if (ai.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(-1);
        } else {
            ai.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
            System.out.println(ai);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner mew = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfTimesToAskForNumbers = mew.nextInt();
        System.out.println("numberOfTimesToAskForNumbers = " + numberOfTimesToAskForNumbers);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimesToAskForNumbers; i++) {
            int amountOfNumbersInThisRound = mew.nextInt();
            System.out.println("amountOfNumbersInThisRound = " + amountOfNumbersInThisRound);
            int a[] = new int[amountOfNumbersInThisRound];
            for (int j = 0; j < amountOfNumbersInThisRound; j++) {
                a[j] = mew.nextInt();
                System.out.println("a[j] = " + a[j]);
            }
            searchForNumbers(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I also renamed the variables to be a bit more clear and added extra printouts so you get feedback during the interaction at the command line.

Side note: Things like this should really be tested with a unit test to ensure all cases are ok instead of having to keep typing things manually to test.

Comment: If time is at a premium, regexes are slower than a single pass over the characters. Even if the JVM may optimize it later, they will need to compile and execute the regex for the first 10k or so iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You are severely overcomplicating your goal. The first rule of efficiency is "avoid doing extra work". Here are places where your code works too much:

- You read characters from the input, parse them into an integer, and then break the number back into digits to check each of them against 1, 2 and 3
- You build an array of candidates, and then you test each element of the array, but the array itself is not needed, as you are only interested in the candidates that pass the 1-2-3 test.

My code below avoids that extra work, and uses a slightly more efficient test to check for existence of 1, 2 or 3. This should result in a significant speedup:

```
import java.util.*;

public class J {

    public static boolean has1or2or3(String s) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) 
            if (c >= '1' && c <= '3') return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void solve(Scanner in) {
        int cases = in.nextInt();
        while (cases-- > 0) {

            // read input, solve problem
            ArrayList<Integer> good = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = in.nextInt();
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                String candidate = in.next();
                if (has1or2or3(candidate)) {
                    good.add(Integer.parseInt(candidate));
                }
            }

            // generate output
            if (good.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(-1);
            } else {
                Collections.sort(good);
                for (int c : good) {
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            solve(in);
        }
    }   
}
```

Sample input and output:

```
1
6
4567 345 1122 89458 8495 473
```

---

```
345 473 1122
```

Answer (score -1):

use hashing for this...
create hashmap with key as 1, 2, and 3 so many numbers will be eliminated

Comment: Building a hashmap is not the answer. While it will work, a hashmap for digits is much cheaper as a size-10 int array. And since we are only interested in finding whether there are 1, 2 or 3s, you do not need the array either. When you need efficient code, using extra datastructures does not help.